# Why does incompressibility imply zero material derivative?

Tags: physics, fluid-dynamics

My course notes define

> The material or substantive derivative, $$\frac{D}{Dt}=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+\textbf{u}\cdot\nabla,$$ where **u** is the fluid velocity

then add,

> In very many circumstances of interest [...] the fluid is effectively incompressible [...] As the piece of fluid moves this means $D\rho/Dt=0$.

I'm trying to understand this. Suppose $$0=\frac{D\rho}{Dt}=\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}+\textbf{u}\cdot\nabla\rho;$$ then
$$\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}=-\textbf{u}\cdot\nabla\rho.\tag{$\ast$}$$

I read $(\ast)$ as saying that any increase-over-time in density (positive $\partial\rho/\partial t$) is entirely accounted for by the movement of the piece of fluid down the spatial gradient of the density scalar field (negative $\textbf{u}\cdot\nabla\rho$), i.e. in the direction of lower density. But that seems like the opposite of what I would expect. What's gone wrong?

Comment: How is $\textbf{u}$ the fluid velocity being defined? It seems like the confusion relates to the sign of that and how it relates to the sign of $\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}$

Comment: @John_Krampf "$\textbf{u}$ is the fluid velocity" is the closest thing to a definition given in this part of the text. Do you have in mind something like $\textbf{u}=u_1\textbf{i}+u_2\textbf{j}+u_2\textbf{k}$?

Comment: If $\mathbf{u}$ and $\nabla \rho$ are pointing in the same direction at a location, ie $\mathbf{u}\cdot\nabla\rho > 0$, then the current will be moving higher density fluid away from the location and lower density fluid into the location. So the rate of change of density had better be negative. Vice-versa, if they are pointing in opposite directions, then the rate of change of density had better be positive.

Comment: Make this precise by computing the time derivative of density using an integral curve of $\mathbf{u}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's linearize the problem to get to the heart of it. (This is the same as analyzing the motion of the fluid along a very small timescale and very small length scale.)

For convenience center the timescale about $t=0$ and the length scale about $\mathbf{x}=0$.

Then:
$$ \rho(\mathbf{x}, t) = \rho(0, 0) + \nabla\rho\cdot (\mathbf{x} - t\mathbf{u}) $$

Why the minus sign? Because the density at position $\mathbf{x}$, time $t$ is carried forward from the density at position $\mathbf{x} - t\mathbf{u}$, time $0$.

In some sense, it may be messing with your intuition because we're used to derivatives as "final minus initial" but in this case the derivative is actually "in minus out", ie "upstream minus downstream".

Comment: I think I've got it. I think my confusion was about "density in a region as various packets of fluid move through it" vs. "density in a packet of fluid as it moves through various regions". Based mostly on staring at your comment, I now read $(\ast)$ as "density in a region increases as higher-density fluid moves into it, i.e. as fluid moves from a region where the density was greater (when that fluid occupied it) into a region where density, until now, was lower".

Comment: Would you mind giving me another nudge? Here's my current understanding: if a fluid is everywhere incompressible then $\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}(\textbf{x},t)=0\;\forall\;\textbf{x},t$; if a fluid is incompressible but non-uniform then we could have $\nabla\rho(\textbf{x},t)\neq0$. In the latter case, do we nonetheless have $\textbf{u}\cdot\nabla\rho(\textbf{x},t)=0\;\forall\;\textbf{x},t$? and if so is that because we're talking about a packet of fluid moving at the background velocity and therefore having a sheath of fluid of uniform density?